# How to add wp editor to custom theme options textarea

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't find any good solution or im to stupid with php. How can i add wordpress editor to textarea's in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this function https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

The editor used by Wordpress is rcalled tinyMCE.-

Answer (score 0):

for texarea fetching are you using advance custome field (ACF). if you want convert these textarea into default wp-editor Please find below link of github.
Add this you can easily use this.
Download editor here- https://github.com/elliotcondon/acf-wordpress-wysiwyg-field

Install as Plugin

```
Download .zip
Extract .zip and rename folder to 'acf-wp-wysiwyg'
Copy the 'acf-wp-wysiwyg' folder into your plugins folder
Activate the plugin via the Plugins admin page
```

Include within theme

```
Download .zip
Extract .zip and rename folder to 'acf-wp-wysiwyg'
Copy the 'acf-wp-wysiwyg' folder into your theme folder (can use sub folders). You can place the folder anywhere inside the 'wp-content' directory
Edit your functions.php file and add the code below (Make sure the path is correct to include the acf-wp-wysiwyg.php file)
```

include_once('acf-wp-wysiwyg/acf-wp_wysiwyg.php');